# Why callback function is bypassed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, callback

I am trying to develop a basic calculator and then introduce various functionalities.

I am new to Python but has been working with VB and c# for quite some time.

At present it has an Entry and three labels. I accept input from keyboard in Entry, and display on one label. Entry is hidden.

e.g. 52+56+36+45=189

User enters 52 and presses + sign

at this stage "+" is displayed on one label, 52 gets transferred to second label and Entry, first label becomes blank.

Till this stage it works properly. Now in step two when user is to enter 56 it allows allows all the keys without any validation and it stops printing output.
This means that callback function is bypassed.

Any help is welcome.

```
import tkinter

from tkinter import *

def callback(input):
    if input.isdigit() or  "." in input or input == "\b":
        print(input)
        return True
    elif "+" in input :
        print(input)
        svLabelOpr.set("+")
        svLabelDisp.set(svLabel.get())
        svLabel.set("")
        svTxt.set("")
        txt.focus_set()
        return False
    else:
        print(input)
        return False


def oddblue(a,b,c):
    svLabel.set(svTxt.get())

frm=Tk()
frm.geometry("250x250")
svTxt = StringVar()
svLabel = StringVar()
svLabelOpr = StringVar()
svLabelDisp = StringVar()

svTxt.trace('w',oddblue)

txt=Entry(frm, width=10, textvariable=svTxt)
txt.place(x=20, y=20)

reg=frm.register(callback)

txt.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%S'))

lbl=Label(frm,anchor='e',width=15,relief=SUNKEN,textvariable=svLabel)
lbl.place(x=50,y=50)

lblOpr=Label(frm,width=3,relief=SUNKEN,textvariable=svLabelOpr)
lblOpr.place(x=180,y=50)

lblDisp=Label(frm,anchor='e', width=15,relief=SUNKEN,textvariable=svLabelDisp)
lblDisp.place(x=50,y=70)

txt.focus_set()

frm.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think your indentation is wrong, please fix it

Answer (score 0):

Adding line:

```
txt.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%S'))
```

here:

```
    elif "+" in input :
        print(input)
        svLabelOpr.set("+")
        svLabelDisp.set(svLabel.get())
        svLabel.set("")
        svTxt.set("")
        txt.focus_set()
        txt.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%S')) # <---Here
        return False
```

Maybe it deregisters due to some case. Configuring it again solves it.

Also, I'm not 100% sure, what you want to do. But, in case, if you want to add the values, you can replace this line:

```
svLabelDisp.set(svLabel.get())
```

with these:

```
try:
    svLabelDisp.set(int(svLabelDisp.get())+int(svLabel.get()))
except ValueError:
    svLabelDisp.set(svLabel.get())
```